# How to export the table to external storage s3 with overwrite?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was trying to export the table to external storage s3 with overwrite.

But overwrite option seemed to be not working.
Below is the query which was used for export:

```
copy into @s3_stage/2020/08/20/test_20200820
    from (select object_construct('id', id, 'user_id', user_id) from sample_table)
    file_format = ( type = json )
    overwrite = true;
```

Result files were outputted as test_20200820_0_*_0.json.gz witch was not guaranteed to be overwritten.
[s3_output_files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrxNo.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just run a rm command before the COPY

```
rm @s3_stage
```

Comment: Thank you @Rajib. Below query which removes files was working fine. `remove @s3_stage/2020/08/20/test_20200820 pattern='.*.json.gz';` Removing before copy looks good for me.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your issue correctly, the problem is that the generated filenames are NOT DETERMINISTIC due to the automatic "splitting" that occurs during the export from Snowflake using the `COPY INTO <location>` command... is that correct?

If so, have you tried using the `SINGLE = TRUE` option (to sidestep the file splitting operation)? For more details, please see the related Snowflake docs [page](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#syntax).

Comment: Thank you @Darren. When I tried below query with single true, it was working correctly. `copy into @s3_stage/2020/08/20/test_20200820.json.gz from (select object_construct('id', id, 'user_id', user_id) from sample_table) file_format = ( type = json ) single = true overwrite = true;` Then, does it mean that single option must be true to apply override true? Is there any way to apply single off and overwrite true at the same time?

Comment: Aside from specifying "SINGLE=TRUE" and overwriting the single (deterministic) file name, I do not believe that there is a way to have the "OVERWRITE=TRUE" remove the target file(s) before creating the new file(s).